# Magento 1.9.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, category

We're having a strange issue on our magento version that is ignoring the `x products per page` attribute... regardless to what we've set it to it just shows a random number of products.

I have cleared the cache, cleared cookies, tried it in incognetio mode but it just shows a random number each time.

Has anyone else had this issue before?